# Uploading a file with billions of record on server and inserting the records in DB

Tags: java, sql

In our application devoloped in java-j2ee we need to import the records from uploaded file from client. The content of file will be of sort as below,

```
id,email,name,last-name,text
1,test@test.com,John,Lives in LA
```

...billion such records in a file.

while the upload process is going on client must regular updates on the process progress.

We are able to upload the File correctly but then for inserting all records in it is also done. But now we want it to happen shortest possible time.

Suggested approaches are,

- Using Multi-threading in

  - Fork join
  - Multiple threads
- JMS

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the *truly* shortest possible time, copy the file in chunks over to the server with the database (maybe using a Java SCP implementation if it's available), then do your DB's version of `LOAD DATA INFILE` (that's MySQL's flavor).

The more sensible approach is just doing batch inserts.

> Suggested approaches are, Using Multi-threading, JMS

Probably won't help. JMS doesn't solve this, and parallelism won't help when you're IO-bound (the size of the pipe or speeds of disks is really what's getting you).

Edit: you *could* see a benefit from multithreading if you have one reader thread that reads the file and another writer thread that does the DB access (producer/consumer). The reason this can help is so you're you're always reading and you're always writing. If you write this correctly, you'll be able to spawn multiple insertion threads so you can try to run it in parallel and see if it helps.